# How to determine which cameras are front and back facing when using HTML5 getUserMedia and enumerateDevices APIs?

Tags: html5-video, getusermedia, mediastream

When accessing the camera using HTML5 getUserMedia APIs, you can either:

1. Request an unspecified "user" facing camera
2. Request an unspecified "environment" facing camera (optionally left or right)
3. Request a list of cameras available

Originally we used the "facing" constraint to choose the camera.  If the camera faces the "user" we show it mirror image as is the convention.

We run into problems, however, when a user does not have exactly 1 user-facing and 1 environment-facing camera.  They might be missing one of these, or have multiple.  This can result in the wrong camera being used, or the camera not being mirrored appropriately.

So we are looking at enumerating the devices.  However, I have not found a way to determine whether a video device is "user facing" and should be mirrored.

Is there any API available to determine whether a video input is "user" facing the in these APIs?

Comment: This is a notorious pain in the xxx neck. It doesn't help that the `label` values for iOS cameras are localized. (But iOS devices only show one front and one back camera even if they are the high-end triple-camera models.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485170/getusermedia-detect-front-camera

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful.  It may be sufficient that I can detect the facing mode after starting the camera.

Answer (score 2):

When you enumerate devices, devices that are an input may have a method called `getCapabilities()`.  If this method is available you may call it to get a [MediaTrackCapabilities](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/archives/20160222/getusermedia.html#media-track-capabilities) object.  This object has a field called `facingMode` which lists the valid `facingMode` options for that device.

For me this was empty on the PC but on my Android device it populated correctly.

Here's a jsfiddle you can use to check this on your own devices: https://jsfiddle.net/juk61c07/4/

Thanks to the comment from O. Jones for setting me in the right direction.

Comment: As of April 2022, browser support for this is spotty: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_inputdeviceinfo_getcapabilities - we are trying to solve the same problem, but this solution does not work for Firefox or Safari at the moment.