# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia - Reverse camera list order / show only rear cameras in HTML5 QR JS Code Scanner

Tags: javascript, android, ios, getusermedia, rendercontrol

I'm using the following QR Code scanner for a PHP application to scan QR codes

[Link to HTML5 JS QR Code Scanner](https://gist.github.com/mebjas/729c5397506a879ec704075c8a5284e8)

[The JS file in question for which I have a local copy of referenced in my HTML file in my case](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/master/minified/html5-qrcode.min.js)

However when selecting cameras on both Android and iOS the list is ordered front cameras first, back cameras last. I am sure this may vary by device, however is there a way to either

A) open rear camera automatically

B) only allow access to back cameras

C) reverse the order of returned cameras so that the bottom comes back at the top of the list, thus putting rear cameras above front cameras in the list

Thanks

[image: dropdown with 1st option selected]

[image: list of cameras order]

Comment: I looked into adding ```facingMode: "environment"``` however that was already set, so i tried ```facingMode: { exact: "environment" }``` however this also didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getUserMedia detect front camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485170/getusermedia-detect-front-camera)

Comment: JSfiddle added here for reference - https://jsfiddle.net/haspden/yecxnbLr/

Answer (score 1):

This is unreasonably messy, sad to say. (Why? Apple is dragging their feet on providing first-class support for getUserMedia(), I suppose because web apps don't have to go through the app store.)

You will have to write a bit of code to use [`.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) to look for the video device you want. In Android devices, the device's `.label` property contains the string `back` for the camera you want.

In iOS devices, the *front* camera is the first one in the result list from `.enumerateDevices()`. It's hard to use the `.label` property because it's localized to the iOS user's own language.  (Android doesn't localize those labels.)

If you'll provide a picklist simply sort it so the back camera is first before you present it.

Here's my research on the topic.

[getUserMedia detect front camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485170/getusermedia-detect-front-camera/65586409#65586409)

Comment: thanks for the information, not a solution as such, but useful regardless... thank you

Comment: If you come up with a better way of handling  this, please let us know. This stuff is a hairball.

Comment: according to the API documentation on this specific example it is possible, have you looked through the attachment? This is for a QR code scanner but perhaps the same logic could be applied? https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode