# WebRTC - Selecting the main camera in a webapp (when the device has multiple back cameras)

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, webrtc, getusermedia

Trying to create a web app that captures images from the browser from the back camera, and struggling to locate the main camera in a multi-camera device.

The problem we are facing is that every manufacturer has different naming conventions, and the order of the cameras in the list is not indicative of which camera is the main camera (the one that doesn't have anything special, like wide-angle, or telephoto, periscope, ...) which has the highest resolution.

When using this website: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/
for my device, for example, the main camera can be located by selecting either camera 2 2 or camera 2 0:
[image: Camera 2 2 and Camera 2 0]

Is there any way to locate the main camera using javascript? or at least get camera characteristics programmatically to select the right one?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485170/getusermedia-detect-front-camera/65586409#65586409 I suspect the `camerax 0` is the wide camera.  Notice that iOS doesn't have this problem; their multiple-camera setup is exposed to the browser via a single device driver instance.

Comment: The bounty says you're looking for a "canonical" answer. Oof. This kind of thing varies widely between  devices makes and software loads. It's about as "canonical" as books of the New Testament were canonical in the second century AD. That is, utter chaos.

Comment: https://webrtchacks.github.io/WebRTC-Camera-Resolution/

Answer (score 0):

FWIW there is a small comment in the Android docs:

> “the primary camera devices (first rear/front camera in the camera
> ID list)”

[I found it here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)

Answer (score 0):

As a fallback scenario you can get MediaStreams from all back cameras and start increasing the resolutions via MediaStreamTrack.applyConstraints (it allows you to change the video resolution on fly) until it will fail or until the video resolution will stop growing. It's not the best solution at all, but maybe it will be helpful if there will be no other way.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if WebRTC API has any information about which one is the "main" camera but you can use the `constraints` while calling the `getUserMedia` to specify the back camera (the one facing away from the user). This should fetch you the back camera it finds first, in the available `mediaDevices` which in most cases is the "main" camera.

Specify `facingMode` as `environment` to choose the back camera. Read more about `facingMode` values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/facingMode#value).

```js
var constraints = {
  facingMode: { exact: "environment" }
  // add any other constraint you want here
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(stream) {
  /* use the stream */
})
.catch(function(err) {
  /* handle the error */
});
```

Comment: That is what we do, but for example on Samsung, we are getting the wide angle which has lower res...

Comment: Did you try specifying the `ideal` value for resolution in `video` constraint? The browser would try to find the camera with the minimum [fitness distance](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dfn-fitness-distance) from the specified value. 
`video: { width: { ideal: 1280 }, height: { ideal: 720 } }`
This could get you the best camera that supports 1280x720 resolution.

Comment: You could use this [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints) from mdn docs to learn more about constraints.

Comment: As mentioned, sorry, but need a more canonical answer with more details. the current answer is very generic.

Comment: Granted the bounty - good luck with your Stackoverflow journey! would be great if you can add more details later (In won't mark the question as answered though, this requires more details sadly).