# Is it possible to block the smartphone from opening gallery?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, input, camera

I have an input for capturing image from the smartphone camera like this below:

```
<input ng-model="fileModel" type="file" name="input_default" accept="image/*;capture=camera"
 capture="camera" capture />
```

If there is no camera on the installed smartphone(OS Android or IOS), the input opens the cell phone gallery. I wanted the user to be alerted that it doesn't have a camera and to not open the device gallery.

I tried this way below, but it didn't work.

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
if(el.capture == undefined){
   // display message user
} else{
   // open the camera normally on the device
}
```

Is it possible to **BLOCK** the smartphone from **opening gallery** using Javascript?

Comment: <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"> this is enough opening camera.  when the doc opened check MediaDevices.getUserMedia() based on result manage it.

Comment: This link has examples on detecting the camera which can be evaluated before rendering your template (i.e. controller constructor). https://stackoverflow.com/a/65586409/4096074 
Once that is done, you should be able to just ng-if between the camera input and a button element that spawns a modal. A direct answer to your question if the behavior can be blocked is no. Once the event is fired, that is up to the browser and outside of the javascript runtime's control.

Comment: As @MarkClark said, you could use the code below to check whether the device has a camera or not and set up a component that would either trigger a camera input or an alert/modal.
`await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(mdiArr => mdiArr.some(mdi => mdi.kind === 'videoinput'))`

Comment: Hi @Przemyslaw ... As I understand it, these checks validate the question whether it has physical camera on the device. I wanted to force the user to not open the device gallery, but I didn't find this type of validation anywhere. I believe there is nothing.

Comment: @Przemyslaw When you don't have a camera app on your smartphone, the photo gallery automatically opens in input. I wanted to block so the user doesn't select a photo from the device's gallery.

Comment: @viana If the `<input type="file" [...] />` launches the gallery on devices without a camera, you could substitute it on those devices with a simple button that would only trigger an alert/modal. That's a work-around, but I don't believe the gallery-opening behavior can be controlled per se.

Comment: In other words, in cases in which the `input` opens the gallery, get rid of this problematic `input` and replace it with a simple `button` to display an alert instead.

Comment: @Przemyslaw But this is my main question, how to check if the device has camera app or not? Because a physical camera check, my code already does. kkkk

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of how to take photo from camera directly with WebRTC by opening camera and taking photo.

This approach is used by many govt website to validate authenticity.

This is the demo,
https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Taking_still_photos/_sample_.demo.html

And this is complete explanation,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Taking_still_photos

```
 (function() {
  // The width and height of the captured photo. We will set the
  // width to the value defined here, but the height will be
  // calculated based on the aspect ratio of the input stream.

  var width = 320;    // We will scale the photo width to this
  var height = 0;     // This will be computed based on the input stream

  // |streaming| indicates whether or not we're currently streaming
  // video from the camera. Obviously, we start at false.

  var streaming = false;

  // The various HTML elements we need to configure or control. These
  // will be set by the startup() function.

  var video = null;
  var canvas = null;
  var photo = null;
  var startbutton = null;

  function showViewLiveResultButton() {
    if (window.self !== window.top) {
      // Ensure that if our document is in a frame, we get the user
      // to first open it in its own tab or window. Otherwise, it
      // won't be able to request permission for camera access.
      document.querySelector(".contentarea").remove();
      const button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = "View live result of the example code above";
      document.body.append(button);
      button.addEventListener('click', () => window.open(location.href));
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function startup() {
    if (showViewLiveResultButton()) { return; }
    video = document.getElementById('video');
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    photo = document.getElementById('photo');
    startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
    .then(function(stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.play();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
    });

    video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
      if (!streaming) {
        height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth/width);

        // Firefox currently has a bug where the height can't be read from
        // the video, so we will make assumptions if this happens.

        if (isNaN(height)) {
          height = width / (4/3);
        }

        video.setAttribute('width', width);
        video.setAttribute('height', height);
        canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
        streaming = true;
      }
    }, false);

    startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
      takepicture();
      ev.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    clearphoto();
  }

  // Fill the photo with an indication that none has been
  // captured.

  function clearphoto() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
  }

  // Capture a photo by fetching the current contents of the video
  // and drawing it into a canvas, then converting that to a PNG
  // format data URL. By drawing it on an offscreen canvas and then
  // drawing that to the screen, we can change its size and/or apply
  // other changes before drawing it.

  function takepicture() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (width && height) {
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

      var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      photo.setAttribute('src', data);
    } else {
      clearphoto();
    }
  }

  // Set up our event listener to run the startup process
  // once loading is complete.
  window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This answer doesn't answer my question. I already knew that there was a way to capture using the camera directly from the browser. My question is if there is a blocking to open the gallery using the 'input'.

Comment: No there is no way, and even if you find a way to hack it. New OS update might make it obsolete. Input was designed basically for file upload, it was never intended for stream or other kind of data. That’s why it will never be possible and also it’s outside security scope, finally it’s user who will decide from where they will upload.